# Игра угадай число Telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Я решил сделать бота телеграм, где надо угадать число. Проблема в том что число одно и тоже, хотя переменная с рандомным числом находиться в цикле. Пытался засунуть 1 функцию, для угадывания числа в цикл, но вместо того чтобы нормально работать, бот начал выводить всегда одно и тоже сообщение. Заранее спасибо <3

```
from telebot import types

import telebot
import random
import config

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKENG)

while True:
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    def start(message):
        if message.text == 'start':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Отгадайте число от 0 до 100, у вас 5 попыток')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, number)
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ошибка!')


    rnumber = random.randint(0, 100)
    def number(message):
        if rnumber == int(message.text):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы отгадали число!')
            return ()
        elif rnumber < int(message.text):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Загаданное число меньше данного.')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, number2)
        elif rnumber > int(message.text):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Загаданное число больше данного.')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, number2)
    def number2(message):
        if rnumber == int(message.text):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы отгадали число!')
            return ()
        elif rnumber < int(message.text):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Загаданное число меньше данного.')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, number3)
        elif rnumber > int(message.text):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Загаданное число больше данного.')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, number3)
    def number3(message):
        if rnumber == int(message.text):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы отгадали число!')
            return ()
        elif rnumber < int(message.text):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Загаданное число меньше данного.')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, number4)
        elif rnumber > int(message.text):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Загаданное число больше данного.')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, number4)
    def number4(message):
        if rnumber == int(message.text):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы отгадали число!')
            return ()
        elif rnumber < int(message.text):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Загаданное число меньше данного.')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, number5)
        elif rnumber > int(message.text):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Загаданное число больше данного.')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, number5)
    def number5(message):
        if rnumber == int(message.text):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы отгадали число!')
            return ()
        elif rnumber < int(message.text):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Загаданное число меньше данного.')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, fail)
        elif rnumber > int(message.text):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Загаданное число больше данного.')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, fail)
    def fail(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Не угадал, загаданное число: {rnumber}')

    print("Бот запущен!")
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Госпади боже, что вы написали? Не делайте так больше

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message: types.Message):
    rnumber = random.randint(0, 100)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Отгадайте число от 0 до 100, у вас 5 попыток')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_number, 1, rnumber)


def get_number(message: types.Message, try_num: int, right_num: int):
    if message.text.isdigit():
        if right_num == int(message.text):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы отгадали число!')
        else:
            if try_num >= 4:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Мимо! Попытки кончились!')
                return

            if right_num < int(message.text):
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Загаданное число меньше введенного.')
            else:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Загаданное число больше введенного.')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_number, try_num + 1, right_num)

    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы ввели не число. Попробуйте еще раз.')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_number, try_num, right_num)
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, я сам знаю что написал код плохо, хотел сделать через цикл, но бот начал спамить сообщением . Ещё раз спасибо.